# Multiple group by with inner query in Oracle

Tags: oracle, join, group-by

I have a table Record with three columns: *p_id, score, city*.

```
P_id       score      city

12          20       Mumbai
12          80       Delhi
12          50       Pune
13          20       Mumbai
13          30       Delhi
13          50       Pune
13          90       Hyd
```

Here I want to have a view with *p_id, max_score, max_score_city, min_score, min_score_city*. Which means for each player, I want max score and the city in which it was scored, min score and the city in which it was scored,

```
p_id     max_score   max_score_city     min_score   min_score_city    
12          80            Delhi             20           Mumbai
13          90            Hyd               30           Mumbai
```

I know I need to apply group by on p_id for min and max score, but how do I join both group by and how to relate player and city in them.

I am new to SQL, can someone please help?

Comment: what RDBMS do you use? What does max_score_city mean? Please add data sample and example of desired result.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I have edited now.

Comment: what about database server version?

Comment: What do you want to do about [ties](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=205c209064b11aafbe62871b2f75994d)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH mins AS 
(SELECT P_id
    ,score AS min_score   
    ,city AS min_score_city    
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P_id ORDER BY score) AS rn
)
, maxs AS 
(SELECT P_id
    ,score AS max_score   
    ,city AS max_score_city    
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P_id ORDER BY score DESC) AS rn
)
SELECT maxs.P_id
    ,maxs.max_score
    ,maxs.max_score_city
    ,mins.min_score
    ,mins.min_score_city
FROM mins
JOIN maxs ON mins.P_id = maxs.P_id
WHERE mins.rn = 1 AND maxs.rn = 1
```

Comment: How will your answer cope with [ties](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=205c209064b11aafbe62871b2f75994d)?

Comment: @Vérace it depends on how author would like to see the list of corresponding cities. For example, we can use RANK instead of ROW_NUMBER and GROUP BY the result using GROUP_CONCAT or STRING_AGG to concatenate the list of cities

Comment: @Nikita: This solved my problems, hence accepting the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a single statement:

```
SELECT
  p_id
 ,MAX
    (
      CASE
        WHEN ScoreDesc = 1 THEN score
        ELSE NULL
      END
    ) AS max_score
 ,MAX
    (
      CASE
        WHEN ScoreDesc = 1 THEN city
        ELSE NULL
      END
    ) AS max_score_city
 ,MAX
    (
      CASE
        WHEN ScoreAsc = 1 THEN score
        ELSE NULL
      END
    ) AS min_score
 ,MAX
    (
      CASE
        WHEN ScoreAsc = 1 THEN city
        ELSE NULL
      END
    ) AS min_score_city
FROM
(
  SELECT
    p_id
   ,score
   ,city
   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p_id ORDER BY Score, city) AS ScoreAsc
   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p_id ORDER BY Score DESC, city) AS ScoreDesc
  FROM
    record
) RecordSummary
WHERE
  ScoreAsc = 1
    OR ScoreDesc = 1
GROUP BY 
  p_id
```

Should be mentioned in case of ties the min/max city will be chosen alphabetically.

Comment: actually there should be OR in WHERE part

Comment: @Nikita thanks for the catch.  Fixed.

Comment: @bbaird: Thanks for the answer, upvoted!